# Apache Karaf hibernate-core feature does not find javax.persistence

Tags: hibernate, apache-karaf, hibernate-envers

I' am facing an issue with hibernate-envers (5.4.17.Final) and karaf 4.2.9,
trying to install the corresponding feature results in an exception:

```
138 │ Active │  80 │ 2.2                │ Java(TM) Persistence API jar
139 │ Active │  80 │ 1.10.10            │ Byte Buddy (without dependencies)
147 │ Active │  80 │ 1.1.1              │ Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint
148 │ Active │  80 │ 2.2.0              │ Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint
153 │ Active │  80 │ 5.1.0.Final        │ hibernate-commons-annotations
154 │ Active │  80 │ 5.4.17.Final       │ hibernate-core
155 │ Active │  80 │ 5.4.17.Final       │ hibernate-osgi
156 │ Active │  80 │ 2.1.3.Final        │ Java Annotation Indexer
157 │ Active │  80 │ 3.3.2.Final        │ JBoss Logging 3
158 │ Active │  80 │ 1.1.1.Final        │ Java Transaction API

karaf@root()> feature:install hibernate-envers
org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve org.hibernate.orm.core/5.4.17.Final: missing requirement [org.hibernate.orm.core/5.4.17.Final] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.persistence)(version>=2.2.0))"
at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:420)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:378)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:332)
at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:257)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:393)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1062)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:998)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Error executing command: Unable to resolve org.hibernate.orm.core/5.4.17.Final: missing requirement [org.hibernate.orm.core/5.4.17.Final] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.persistence)(version>=2.2.0))"
karaf@root()>
```

According to the exception the javax.persistence 2.2.0 bundle is missing,
however listing all bundles shows the javax.persistence with 2.2.
How and where would I fix this? Is it a hibernate issue?

Cheers Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Starting from scratch again seemed to fix this issue, also i did not add the
hibernate repo again (first attempt I did feature:repo-add hibernate 5.4.17.Final), since it was already there, possibly that seems the error, although rather weird.